# Problema de conversion a string

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy tratando de imprimir el resultado de una consulta en un excel, he realizado todos los pasos previos para este proceso, pero tengo este error.

> "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Estos son mis dos metodos.

```html
    public function reportes(Request $request)
    { 
        $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);

        $conteo = DB::table('usuarios')
              ->join('users', 'usuarios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
              ->select('usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id', DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
              ->groupBy(['usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id'])
              ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
              ->get();

        return view('usuario.reportes',compact('conteo'));

        
     }


    public function excel()
    {        
       
        Excel::create('LaravelExcel', function($excel) {
            $excel->sheet('Excelsheet', function($sheet) {
             
          $conteo = DB::table('usuarios')
              ->join('users', 'usuarios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
              ->select('usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id', DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
              ->groupBy(['usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id'])
              ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
              ->get();

                $sheet->fromArray($conteo);
                $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
            });
        })->export('xls');
    }
```

Supongo que mandar todo por ->get() pueda ser el origen del problema, pero si fuese asi no podria cambiarlo, tendria otro error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En qué línea está el error?

Comment: Solo doy clic en el boton para descargar el excel, pero no puede hacerse por que el metodo excel no puede convertir los datos a string, hay algo mal en el metodo excel, pero no se que es.

Comment: Mira Shaz, si por ejemplo yo mando una consulta por eloquen asi usuarios::all(), funciona, pero con el constructor de consultas, como lo tento yo, DB::table(), me aparece ese error.

Comment: ¿Acaso es tan compleja la consulta que no se pueden usar las relaciones de eloquent?

Comment: pues... para mi si :(

Comment: Bueno el problema es que get es assoc no array puedes hacer un cast `$conteo = (array) $conteo;`

Answer (score 0):

la solucion fue poner un json_decode despues de la consulta.

```html
    public function excel()
    {        
       
        Excel::create('LaravelExcel', function($excel) {
            $excel->sheet('Excelsheet', function($sheet) {
             

          $conteo = DB::table('usuarios')
              ->join('users', 'usuarios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
              ->select('usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id', DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
              ->groupBy(['usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id'])
              ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
              ->get();

             $conteo = json_decode( json_encode($conteo), true);

                $sheet->fromArray($conteo);
                $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
            });
        })->export('xls');
    }
```

Lo se, lo se, hay que hacer las cosas bonitas pero apenas empiezo, gracias por sus comentarios